# Expected to find a valid target react dnd

Tags: reactjs

I am experiencing this error with react dnd. The weird thing is that it depends on the key i specify to my react component. if i specify index, one part of my function fires this error, and when i specify item.id, another part doesnt fire. it doesnt make sense. please help.

When I specify the key to be index, the error fires when forum has no parent. however when i specify the key to be forum._id, the error fires when forum has parent. i dont know what to do, please help :)

Please visit this sandbox to reproduce:
https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-wind-hklt6

To reproduce:
Drag item 1ba on top of item 1, and then drag the item 1ba down the path.

Forum.jsx

```
const Forum = ({ forum, forums, setForums, move, find }) => {
  const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: "forum",
    hover: throttle((item, monitor) => {
      if (item._id === forum._id) {
        return;
      }
      if (!monitor.isOver({ shallow: true })) {
        return;
      }

      if (!canDrop) return;

      move(item, forum, forum.parent);

      item = forum;
    }, 200),
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: monitor.isOver(),
      canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
    }),
  });

  const [, drag, preview] = useDrag({
    item: {
      _id: forum._id,
      title: forum.title,
      type: "forum",
      children: forum.children,
      parent: forum.parent,
    },
    isDragging(props, monitor) {
      return props._id == monitor.getItem()._id;
    },
  });

  const getChildren = async (forumId) => {
    const _forums = await ForumService.getChildren(forumId, forums);
    setForums(_forums);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper ref={drop}>
      <ForumContainer ref={drag}>
        {!!forum.childrenIds?.length && (
          <div>
            {!forum.isOpen ? (
              <ForumChevron
                className="fas fa-chevron-down"
                onClick={() => getChildren(forum._id)}
              ></ForumChevron>
            ) : (
              <ForumChevron
                className="fas fa-chevron-up"
                onClick={() =>
                  setForums(ForumService.resetChildren(forum._id, forums))
                }
              ></ForumChevron>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
        <ForumTitle>{forum.title}</ForumTitle>
      </ForumContainer>

      {forum.children && !!forum.children.length && (
        <ForumChildrenWrapper>
          {forum.children.map((child, index) => (
            <Forum
              forum={child}
              setForums={setForums}
              forums={forums}
              key={index}
              move={move}
              find={find}
            />
          ))}
        </ForumChildrenWrapper>
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Forum;
```

ForumManager.jsx

```
    if (!item.parent) {
      console.log("here 1");
      const dest = findItem(afterItem._id, _forums);
      if (!dest.children) dest.children = [];

      foundItem.parent = afterItem._id;
      const idx = _forums.findIndex((f) => f._id === item._id);
      _forums.splice(idx, 1);

      if (dest.parent === foundItem._id) {
        dest.parent = "";
        if (foundItem.children.length) {
// When key is item.id, error shows up here
          console.log("parent & has children");
          for (let child of [...foundItem.children]) {
            if (child._id === dest._id) {
              child.children.splice(0, 0, {
                ...foundItem,
                children: [],
                childrenIds: [],
              });
            }
            _forums.push(child);


          }
        } else {
          console.log("no children");
          dest.children.unshift({
            ...foundItem,
            children: [],
            childrenIds: [],
          });
        }
      } else {
// When key is index, error shows up here


        console.log("no parent");
        console.log(dest);
        dest.parent = "";
        dest.children.splice(0, 0, {
          ...foundItem,
          children: [],
          childrenIds: [],
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: anyone? please help i ran out of ideas!

Comment: What is "this error"? You mention it a few times, but I can't actually see an error message anywhere in the question.

Comment: it says in the title

Comment: anyone please? i posted an update with the sandbox for reproduction of the error, see description

Comment: anyone please? i dont know how to do this

Answer (score 3):

Try adding debounce to the hover handler (with trailing option).  The components are updating too quickly by setting the state before DnD could catch up, and the target ID had changed by the time the user dropped the item.

Also - don't use  index as the key, as it will change each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove monitor.canDrop() inside collect function, then it works. Not sure, but this is one way.